# Uncaught ReferenceError: RefreshSkinList is not defined(…)

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the Uncaught ReferenceError: RefreshSkinList is not defined error when trying to make this work. Any help is appreciated.

This code is supposed to show a list of images divided in pages. When you click on a image it should make a div popup on the page and show an actual bigger image and a button saying CHANGE SKIN.

```
var mySkin = -1;
function RefreshSkinList(showPage){     
    if(showPage == undefined) showPage = 0;
    else if(showPage > 0) showPage--;
    $.post( "skin_list.php", {page: showPage, race: $("#f_skin_race").val(), gender: $("#f_skin_gender").val(), weight: $("#f_skin_weight").val(), category: $("#f_skin_category").val()}, function( data ) {
    }).done( function(){
        $("#skinlist").empty();
    }).success( function( data ){
        var skinDump = jQuery.parseJSON(data);          
        skinDump.skins.forEach(function(skin){
            $("#skinlist").append("<img onclick=\"SkinChangePreview(" + skin.id + ");\" src=\"https://modern-rp.com/images/skins/" + skin.id + ".jpg\">");
        });
        if(skinDump.matches == 0){
            $("#skinlist").append("No skins match your filters.");
        }else{
            if(skinDump.matches > 36){
                $("#skinlist").append("<br />Pages: ");
                for(var i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(skinDump.matches/36); i++){
                    $("#skinlist").append("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"RefreshSkinList(" + i + ");\">" + i + "</a> ");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
function SkinChangePreview(skinid){
    $("#skinchange").empty();
    $("#skinchange").append("<img style=\"min-height: 335px;\" src=\"https://modern-rp.com/images/skins2/" + skinid + ".png\"><br />");
    $("<input type="submit" value=\"Use This Skin\">").addClass("black_button skinChangeConfirm").appendTo("#skinchange");
    $("#skinchange").fadeIn();
    mySkin = skinid;
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: $("#skinchange").offset().top}, 1500);
}
$(function(){
    $("#skinchange").delegate(".skinChangeConfirm", "click", function(){
        $.post("skinchange.php", {skin: mySkin}, function(data){                
        }).done( function(data){
            $("#skinchange").html(
                "<br /><div id=\"_info\" class=\"ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all\" style=\"padding: 0 .7em;\">" + 
                "<p><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-info\" style=\"float: left; margin-right: .3em;\"></span>" + 
                data + 
                "</p></div><br />"
            );
        });
    });
    RefreshSkinList();      
});
```

Comment: the error you got when you click ??

Comment: `RefreshSkinList(" + i + ");` should be `RefreshSkinList(i);`

Comment: @Mahi No it shouldn't. That will evaluate `i` when he clicks, it won't put the variable from the loop into the attribute.

Comment: Is the function defined in the global scope? When `onclick` is evaluated, it's evaluated in the global scope.